# ionic 3 angular dynamic menu

Tags: angular, ionic3, navigator

I recently saw a website built using ionic angular and one of the coolest thing I liked is:

In the browser the typical navigator links like service, contact us etc. render on the top right corner in the header.

However, if you open it in the mobile device the same links render as hamburger menu on the top left which u can click to navigate.

I did not find anything like that in ionic component docs that can dynamically change the layout of the navigator menu. How do you do this?

Comment: Wasn't it done with plain Bootstrap?

Comment: the artical says they build using ionic angular and firebase

Comment: You could add the buttons both in the header and in the side menu, and then hide them according to the current size of the window (you can get that information using Ionic's `Platform` component)

Comment: sure just a duplication of functionality though